# Getting an error of: 'google' is not defined while building Google Maps infobox using React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

In the code:

```js
const MapWithInfo = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,

   containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    center: {lat: 41.9, lng: -87.624,}
  }),
  withScriptJS
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={15}
    defaultCenter={props.center}
  >
    <InfoBox
      defaultPosition={new google.maps.LatLng(props.center.lat, props.center.lng)}
      options={{ closeBoxURL: ``, enableEventPropagation: true }}
    >
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: `yellow`, opacity: 0.75, padding: `12px` }}>
        <div style={{ fontSize: `16px`, fontColor: `#08233B` }}>
          Hello from Taipei
        </div>
      </div>
    </InfoBox>
    <Marker
     position= {props.center}/>
  </GoogleMap>
);
```

I am getting an error of 'google' is not defined. I am adding the API through withScriptJS just as shown in the react-google-maps documentation but it doesnt seem to work. 
I am getting an error on the line:

```
    defaultPosition={new google.maps.LatLng(props.center.lat, props.center.lng)}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814211/818506 This might help, in case someone lands on this page

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply put

```
<InfoBox
  defaultPosition={props.center}
  options={{ closeBoxURL: ``, enableEventPropagation: true }}
>
```

You don't have to call google anymore.

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesnt work. I am able to view the map with the marker but I am no longer able to move the map if i do this and the infobox doesnt show on the map.